# How to communicate with a nested directive without modifying it in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which has an OK button. I want to create another directive using this directive. The outer directive has a dropdown control. When the user clicks on the OK button of the nested directive I need to access the selected value of the dropdown control. The problem is I cannot modify the nested control as it does not belong to our team. Is there any way I can do this? I am new to angular and I am not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Can you share the OK directive's code? let's see if it has data-binding to outer directives or any interface.

Comment: If you don't want to modify it, then you can decorate it http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/